# Loading libraries and additional modules with requirejs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, requirejs

I'm struggling to understand how to load an external library and additional module using requirejs.

This is what I have:

This works OK, but doesn't seem right to me:

```
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      highcharts: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/highcharts'
  }
});
requirejs.config({
  paths: {
      exporting: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/modules/exporting'
  }
});
```

I was sort of expecting this to have worked:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
      highcharts: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/highcharts',
      exporting: 'http://localhost:3000/hicharts/js/modules/exporting'
  }
});
```

But it doesn't seem to expose the exporting module, even though it gets called from the web server. Am I missing anything here, and does anyone know where its documented ? I can't seem to find much that discusses it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a [Highcharts NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts) that contains Highcharts, Highstock and Highmaps plus all modules. Start by installing Highcharts as a node module and save it as a dependency in your package.json:

`npm install highcharts --save`

Load with require:

```
var Highcharts = require('highcharts');
// Load module after Highcharts is loaded
require('highcharts/lib/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', { /*Highcharts options*/ });
```

More information and examples can be found in [Highcharts General Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm) and this [Highcharts article](http://www.highcharts.com/component/content/article/2-news/188-highcharts-optimized-for-npm).